# Display an Activity indicator for a ajax web page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a page that request the data every specific duration (10 secs) via ajax request,
the page should still running for a long time, i am searching for a technique to **let the user know if an error occurred in the page** (probably JS error, or server error) 
ex: a green light while the page running ,and a red light in case of error

I am using jquery (ajax) library

**note : I am not searching for a ajax loader (gif)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: ...,
        data: ....,
        success: function() {
            $('#indicator').css(backgroundColor: 'red'); // you can set background animated image
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#indicator').css(backgroundColor: 'green'); // you can set background animated image
        }
    });
```